# Error with lazy loading in Entity Framework Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am having an error on my web page:

`{"The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection."}`

It occours herein my view:

```
@model Service_Monitor_Web_Interface.Models.DashBoardViewModel
...    
=> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Service.Name)
```

Here is my ViewModel class:

```
    public class DashBoardViewModel
{

    public int NumberOfUsers { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> recentUsers { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<UserActivityLog> logs { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Service_Monitor_Domain.Entities.ServiceStatusHistory> serviceStatus { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my controller for the class:

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DashBoardViewModel vm = new DashBoardViewModel();  

        var dbs = new EFServiceStatusHistoryRepository();

        vm.serviceStatus = dbs.GetAllEnabledLatestStatusLog();

        return View(vm);
    }
```

and here is my function that access the db:

```
  public List<ServiceStatusHistory> GetAllEnabledLatestStatusLog()
    {
        List<ServiceStatusHistory> list = null;
        try
        {
            using (var db = new EFDbContext())
            {
                //var results = db.ServiceStatusHistory.Where(h => h.Service.Enabled)
                //                  .OrderByDescending(h => h.Id)
                //                  .GroupBy(h => h.Service.Id)
                //                  .Select(grp => grp.FirstOrDefault());

                var results = db.ServiceStatusHistory
                            .Where(x => x.Service.Enabled)
                            .GroupBy(x => x.Service)
                             .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.time).FirstOrDefault());

                list = results.ToList();
            }
            return list;
        }
        catch
        {
            //Error
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Here is my entity:

```
    public class ServiceStatusHistory
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Forenkey to service
    [Required]
    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ServiceStatus Status { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Messages { get; set; }

    [Required]
    //Time Logged in the db
    public DateTime time { get; set; }

    [Required]
    //Time the service last called the update method on the client
    public DateTime LastUpdateTime { get; set; }
 }
```

I think it has something to do with lazy loading. But I have not had this problem before when querying the same table? However it was just a simple select query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider "Eager" loading of the Service class in your GetAllEnabledLatestStatusLog(). Be sure to include using System.Data.Entity
`using System.Data.Entity
 var results = db.ServiceStatusHistory
                            .Include("Service")
                            .Where(x => x.Service.Enabled)
                            .GroupBy(x => x.Service)
                            .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.time).FirstOrDefault());`

See [MSDN Loading Related Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

Comment: I think it is "Service", not "Services". Use strictly typed version of include to eliminate such kind of typo errors:  .Include(x => x.Service).

Comment: @JimSTAT Please see my comment on the other answer as it is also relevant to your answer. Include is underlined red in visual studio.

Comment: @Zapnologica Be sure to include using System.Data.Entity

Comment: @JimSTAT, It now throws an error after executing the result: ` Unable to cast the type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[[Service_Monitor_Domain.Entities.Service, Service Monitor Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Service_Monitor_Domain.Entities.ServiceStatusHistory, Service Monitor Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' to type ` to continue

Comment: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[[Service_Monitor_Domain.Entities.Service, Service Monitor Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Service_Monitor_Domain.Entities.ServiceStatusHistory, Service Monitor Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: I fixed it:

Here is the query That worked: ` var result = db.ServiceStatusHistory
                                    .Include("Service")
                                           .Where(x => x.Service.Enabled)
                                           .GroupBy(x => x.Service)
                                            .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.time).FirstOrDefault());`

Comment: @Zapnologica - good work.  Updated answer to reflect your results.  Oddly my original post did not return errors in my setup but I must have missed something.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that the problem here is that in your query you are not explicitly loading the related entities (in this case, `ServiceStatusHistory.Service`), presumably Lazy Loading is on by default.

So later on when you refer to `item.Service.Name`, the underlying EF class realises that it needs to load these related entities - except that the associated `ObjectContext` (in this case, `EFDbContext`) has long since been disposed.

So probably the simplest way to fix this is to modify your query to [.Include()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) the related `Service` entities

```
 var results = db.ServiceStatusHistory
                    .Include("Service")
                    .Where(x => x.Service.Enabled)
                    .GroupBy(x => x.Service)

                    .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.time).FirstOrDefault());
```

or you could turn off [lazy loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontextoptions.lazyloadingenabled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that query:

```
using (var db = new EFDbContext())
{
   db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled=false;
   //use original query here
}
```

Comment: I changed my query and I am getting an error on the Include: `System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Linq.IGrouping<Service_Monitor_Domain.Entities.Service,Service_Monitor_Domain.Entities.ServiceStatusHistory>>' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Linq.IGrouping<Service_Monitor_Domain.Entities.Service,Service_Monitor_Domain.Entities.ServiceStatusHistory>>'`

Comment: ` db.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` also doesnt work.  It says `EFDbContext does not contain a defintion for contextOptions`

Comment: @Zapnologica - yikes, my bad;see updated answer, it should work now. If not, ignore the second option anyway as the first is safer (since it won't eagerly load anything except what you tell it to)

Comment: Thanks, Regarding the turning off of lazy loading. my results where fairly odd. If i turned lazy loading off. my query would return a list of 4 items. and service would be valid for the first item and after that ie item 2 - 4 it was null ?

Comment: That's odd, but perhaps it has something to do with the actual underlying table structure - are you sure that items 2-4 actually have a valid Service entity in the database?

Comment: I did chack that and yes they did. An I know they do because when I use the include it returns a service for all of them.

Comment: ok well in that case maybe it's better to use the `include` method then  - as I previously mentioned it's probably better anyway because it gives you exact control over what to eagerly load.